# Get data id attribute value of an specific image element from list of image element using jquery?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a product table and product image table. Each product may have multiple images. In the product edit form I rendered all images of that product. I want to delete every single image by clicking on a cross button which is included with every single image.

In order to delete a specific image I need the image id, so I have passed that id using a `data-id` attribute. However when I click on the cross button I always get the first image id. I need that clicked image id. How can I get it?

```js
$(document).on("click", "#imagePosition", function() {
  var id = $("#singleImage").attr("data-id");
  console.log(id);
  
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/destroySingleImage",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      id: id
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('hi');
      alert("added to cart");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<label for="images">Product Images :</label> @if(count($product->images)> 0)
<div class="row">
  @foreach ($product->images as $image)
  <div style="position:relative;">
    <button type="submit" class="close imagePosition" id="imagePosition">
      <span>&times;</span>
    </button>
    <img alt="preview image" id="singleImage" src="{{asset('storage/'.$image->image)}}" alt="image" data-id="{{$image->id}}" style="width:300px;height:300px; margin:5px;">
  </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is because your loop is generating HTML elements with the same `id` attribute repeated multiple times. This is invalid as the value of `id` attributes must be unique within the DOM.

To fix the issue remove the `id` and use `class` attributes instead. You can then traverse the DOM from the reference to the `button` which raises the click event to find the related `.singleimage` element and read its `data-id`.

Also note that I made a couple of tweaks to the logic to meet best practices, such as using `data()` instead of `attr()` when working with data attributes, and also placing the CSS rules in an external stylesheet instead of inline `style` attributes.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".imagePosition", function() {
  var id = $(this).next('.singleimage').data('id');
  console.log(id);

  // AJAX request here...
});
```

```css
.row>div {
  position: relative;
}

.singleimage {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="images">Product Images :</label>
<div class="row">
  <div>
    <button type="submit" class="close imagePosition">
      <span>&times;</span>
    </button>
    <img alt="preview image" class="singleimage" src="{{asset('storage/'.$image->image)}}" alt="image" data-id="001" />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <button type="submit" class="close imagePosition">
        <span>&times;</span>
      </button>
    <img alt="preview image" class="singleimage" src="{{asset('storage/'.$image->image)}}" alt="image" data-id="002" />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <button type="submit" class="close imagePosition">
      <span>&times;</span>
    </button>
    <img alt="preview image" class="singleimage" src="{{asset('storage/'.$image->image)}}" alt="image" data-id="003" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot man.it works.Another help needed when i delete the image using ajax it also exists in page until i reload the page.How can i solve this problem?can you please help me.

Comment: Sure, to do that call `remove()` on the `img` element in the AJAX callback